# Systray icon tooltip upon keyboard focus (Win 32)

Tags: win32gui

I want to display the statistics of my application from the system tray, when the user focuses the application's system tray icon. To achieve this, I used Shell_NotifyIcon(), but it has the limitation of max string size of 64 chars. 
So, I created my own tooltip window using "CreateWindow()" (I am using Win32 APIs), and it works fine when I hover the mouse over the icon. But it doesnt work when systray icon is focussed using only keyboard.

When I debugged the app, it appeared that there were no windows-messages captured when icon was focussed using keyboard. But I get WM_MOUSEMOVE messages when I hover the mouse over the icon.

Are there any windows-messages sent out when systray icons are focused using keyboard (i.e Win+B --> use arrow keys to navigate to your icon)?

Any alternate suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

A System Tray icon tooltip is limited to 64 characters only on Windows versions prior to Windows 2000.  In Windows 2000, the tooltip limit was increased to 128 characters.

And there are messages when the icon is focused/activated via keyboard.  You may have to ask the System Tray for them via `NIM_SETVERSION`.

Read the documentation:

[Notifications and the Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Shell_NotifyIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There is a lot of information about handling keyboard/mouse messages in the Remarks.